# Localisation of application in Linux

Tags: linux, gtk

I have an application where UI language is in English,

how can i make its UI set to other languages such as Italy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the application has already been translated and you have the translation installed:

```
LANG=locale application
```

You can see which locales are defined on your system with:

```
localedef --list-archive
```

In your case the locale would probably be "`it_IT`"

Comment: You might want to set the locale in /etc/profile or ~/.profile

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to use gettext. Alter the code to use _ or gettext() for the UI strings, then extract them and translate the .po files into the different languages.